# HttpClient4.5 throw exception on connecting server

Tags: java, spring, apache

I am want to hit the one rest service using httpclient. But facing problem. Here is my program to hit server. If I run this program from my local machine then it hit server fine and get the response as well. 
But When I host this program to server and then hit the Rest Server then it thows and exception. I really not able to understand what is different between local and server enviornment.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse resp = null;
            String url = "http://gigilitytest.cloud.cms500.com/MMServer/mycircle/saveuserinfo";
            URI uri = null;
            RequestResult reqResult = new RequestResult();
            try {
                uri = new URI(url);
                httpPost.setURI(uri);
                System.out.println("***********************************----------1");
                resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println("***********************************----------2");
                System.out.println("resp:" + resp);

                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent());
                reqResult = gson.fromJson(reader, RequestResult.class);
                reader.close();
                httpPost.releaseConnection();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Exception is :

"preferedGenderType":"","imgUrl":"https%253A%252F%252Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.`net%252Fv%252Ft1.0-1%252Fp50x50%252F16194964_10208251611276804_5467876133040299192_n.jpg%253Foh%253D63a59ee0a5dc9cdb0771135ffa7fab2d"} org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to gigilitytest.cloud.cms500.com:80 [gigilitytest.cloud.cms500.com/10.101.4.223] failed: Connection refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) at com.gigility.rs.UserProfileRS.saveUserProfile(UserProfileRS.java:93) at com.controller.AjaxController.saveUserProfile(AjaxController.java:113) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134) ... 51 more`

Comment: Maybe there is some firewall somewhere? Did you test the connection with `curl`?

Comment: no, Could you tell me more about this curl option?

Comment: `curl` is a command line tool allowing you to send the exact same request as your program to be sure that the problem is not coming from the server or from the network.